# Laravel returns a html page with data instead of a response json in my script.js

Tags: php, html, laravel, fetch

I have to porting a php website in laravel and in my original website JavaScript file i call a fetch in a .php file of contents and return a json. In laravel call the fetch in a {{route('contents')}} and then in web.php i create the route
`Route::get("/contents","ContentsController@contents")->name('contents')`. And so in ContentsController.php i create:

```
function contents(){
    $CONTENUTI=[
         ["title"=>"abc",
           "img"=>"https....",
           "Id"=>"01"],
         ["title"=>"def", 
           .....
          ];
     return response()->json($CONTENTS)
```

But in my website console there's this message:route('contents') 404 not found i try also with return $CONTENTS but it shows me a white page with the json and not in my view

Comment: It seems like you have typo in your route, `ContentsController@contentes` it should be `ContentsController@contents` maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the error, in my code I wrote it correctly

Comment: If I understand that properly, calling the route directly results in the json being returned properly while fetching the result in JavaScript fails. That would mean, you have to post the contents of your js file as well.

Comment: All right, so how do I do this?